# How can I use Multiple GPU's During Model training on Kaggle

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gpu, kaggle

On Kaggle I have 2 GPU T4, but I don't understand how I can use them in Pytorch or adapt the code to train on 2 gpu's

[pic of 2 gpu's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI7oO.png)

My training code:

```
for epoch in range(2):

    running_loss = 0.0
    for data in tqdm(dataset):
        inputs, labels = data
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()
```

Answer (score 1):

To run on multiple GPU:s you must adopt the training to run distributed training.
Pytorch has documentation regarding the area here:

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/distributed/home.html

From there you can find what case fits you the best.

I also found another source which goes into the distributed training area:
https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-use-multiple-gpus-in-pytorch/

There they talk about three different methods, where the first (Data parallelism) is the most common for simpler and smaller models, as it is the easiest to adapt to.